# Finding the length and cordinates of a Chord

Tags: circles

(-3, 9) is the midpoint of a chord within a circle with center (7,-1) and radius 18. How do I calculate the length of the chord and find the coordinates of the ends of the chord by completing the square?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.